# Kubernetes Ingress Nginx malformed requests

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-elb, nginx-ingress

I am using AWS managed kubernetes (EKS) and Nginx Ingress helm chart, and whenever I open Nginx ingress controller logs, I frequently encounter improperly formatted requests like the following examples:

```
10.0.7.208 - - [02/Oct/2023:22:48:17 +0000] "\x00" 400 150 "-" "-" 0 0.000 [] [] - - - - b00d3eabe62118426a3cd2a285707f29
10.0.8.6 - - [02/Oct/2023:22:48:19 +0000] "\x00" 400 150 "-" "-" 0 0.000 [] [] - - - - 2cb81d594767974f0bdd68e5cc241874
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue or identify the source of these requests?

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to the proxy protocol not being enabled on the AWS load balancer. You can learn more about configuring the proxy protocol here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-proxy-protocol.html

Comment: I already have Proxy protocol v2 enabled in target groups